# Apply mat-form-field-invalid conditionally based on boolean Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I am working on a reactive form and I have a constraint on the password field. I want to apply the class '`mat-form-field-invalid`' on the  manually based on the value of a boolean.

my HTML

```
<mat-form-field
          appearance="outline"
          [ngClass]="{
            'mat-form-field-invalid':
              !passwordsRequirementSatisfied && f.password.touched
          }"
        >
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'"
            (keyup)="validatePassword()"
            formControlName="password"
            required
          />
          <button
            mat-icon-button
            matSuffix
            (click)="hidePassword = !hidePassword"
            type="button"
          >
            <mat-icon>{{
              hidePassword ? "visibility_off" : "visibility"
            }}</mat-icon>
          </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually changing a class to affect style, you can do it the Angular/Reactive Forms way by writing a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators). You apply it when you define the form control in the component logic.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
 //Here showError is a boolean variable 
[class.mat-form-field-invalid]="showError"
```